# Combine arrays with a common value into a new array

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I am working on a project and I am stuck on this my question is I have one array which is like below

```
$arr1  =   array(
        array
        (
            'id' => '1',
            'city' => 'A.bad',
        ),
        array
        (
            'id' => '2',
            'city' => 'Pune',
        ),
        array
        (
            'id' => '1',
            'city' => 'Mumbai',
        )
        );
```

and I have to compare the this by id and I want the output like below.

```
$result = array(
       array(
          'id'='1',
          'city'='A.bad','Mumbai'
      ),
      array(
          'id'='2',
          'city'='Pune'
      )
);
```

if we have same id as in the first one is `A.bad` so it will take it and in the third one it has id 1 and city as `mumbai` so it will combine as id 1 and city as `a.bad`,`mumbai` and other records are filtered in same manner.

Comment: whats the question? this is just some array that you have

Comment: elaborate your question, be more exact: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop through the array and generate a new `array` depending on the `id`.You can try this -

```
$new = array();
foreach($arr1 as $array) {
    $new[$array['id']]['id']= $array['id'];
    // check if the city value set for that id
    // if set the concatenate else set with the city name 
    $new[$array['id']]['city']= (isset( $new[$array['id']]['city'])) ?  ($new[$array['id']]['city'] . ',' . $array['city']) : $array['city'];
}
```

[Fiddle](https://eval.in/555987)

If you are getting that data from database the you can group them in the query also.